# Efficiently iterating and updating large amounts of data from a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, dapper

I have a table in SQL Server that is storing files in binary format. Each row is on average ~3MB and there are tens of thousands of rows. What I'd like to do (since I must keep these tables around), is query each row, then run some compression on the binary data, and then re-insert the data (by updating each row).

My current naive implementation simply does something similar to this (using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)):

```
var files = con.QueryAsync<MyClass>("SELECT ID, Content from Files");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    ... compress file.Content here
    con.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE Files SET Content = @NewContent WHERE ID = @ID", { ... });
}
```

Obviously this is very inefficient because it first loads all files into memory, etc... I was hoping  can somehow do a query/update in "batches", and IDEALLY I'd like to be able to run each batch asynchronously (if that's even possible).

Any suggestions would be appreciated (using SQL Server BTW).

Comment: See sql command line tools : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'm aware of these, but I'm not sure how they help in this scenario.  I need to use C# to manipulate the data before updating the rows.

Comment: The transfer mechanism is faster using the utilities.  So you can make main function a bat file that send the data to c# standard input and then take standard output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entire operation could be done on db instance, without moving data over network to application and back, using built-in function [COMPRESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> This function compresses the input expression, using the GZIP algorithm. The function returns a byte array of type varbinary(max).

```
UPDATE Files 
SET Content = COMPRESS(Content)
WHERE ID IN (range); -- for example 1k rows per batch
```

If you are using SQL Server version lower than 2016 or you need "custom" compression algorithm you could use [user-defined CLR function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: But with this way, you send to the DB all files - this is more bad than load them to the memory together!

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Everything is done on DB instance. There is no data movement to application over network.\

Comment: @Chayim Friedman: not sure what you mean? The files according to the question are already in the DB....!

Comment: Yes, I do need to use a custom compression algorithm.  Can you expand on what you mean by 'user-defined CLR function'?  I haven't seen that term before.

Comment: I've found information on the topic here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-2017  which you may want to include in your answer.  I think this may be the best approach and I'll mark your answer as correct unless someone gives a better option within the next day.  Thanks!

Comment: @jewnbug97 Sure.